# How to add quotation on a string for python?

Tags: python

I want to add quotation marks around a string.

My code looks like this:

```py
first_name = "albert"

last_name = "einstein"

message = "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."
    
print(f"{first_name.title()} {last_name.title()} once said, {message} ")
```

The output is:

```
Albert Einstein once said, A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new.
```

But I want the output to be:

```
Albert Einstein once said, "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new".
```

Comment: Have you tried `'"'` + your_current_string + `'"'`
?

Answer (score 3):

Simply change the code to

```
first_name = "albert"

last_name = "einstein"

message = '"A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."'

print(f"{first_name.title()} {last_name.title()} once said, {message} ")
```

Use single quotes around the original string, to make the other quotes - `""` shown.

You could also use a slash - `\`. This acts as an escape sequence.

```
print(f"{first_name.title()} {last_name.title()} once said, \"{message} \" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods to do this:

1. You can escape the double quotes so something like:
   Putting a backslash behind the double quotes escapes it and takes it as part of the string instead of the endpoint

```
print(f"{first_name.title()} {last_name.title()} once said, \"{message} \" ")
```

2. The other way is to use single quotes for f, then you can use double quotes unescaped

```
print(f'{first_name.title()} {last_name.title()} once said, "{message}" ')
```

Comment: And as someone else mentioned you can use the same escaping within double quotes / using single quotes for the message variable and put the double quotes inside there too

Answer (score 1):

The quotes need to be inserted explicitly in the string something like this

```
# Case-1
print(f"""{first_name.title()} {last_name.title()} once said, "{message}" """)
```

The outcome is

```
Albert Einstein once said, "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."
```

Since the quote appears after the `.`, hence the quotes should go into the message string

```
# Case -2
first_name = "albert"
last_name = "einstein"
message = '"A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new".'

print(f"{first_name.title()} {last_name.title()} once said, {message} ")
```

Notice that in first example, I have used tripple quotes `"""` to enclose the string and in second case, its double quotes `"` inside single `'`. Many such combinations work in python. Otherwise writing the message like below also works, but requires escaping the double quotes

```
message = "\"A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new\"."
```

Also have a look at these docs
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals